# Linux VM hanged after CommVault Backup

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, linux-kernel

The last messages in /var/log/message before I had to restart the linux-server was:

```
Mar  4 20:48:24 extranet2 kernel: Mem-Info:
Mar  4 20:48:24 extranet2 kernel: active_anon:8 inactive_anon:0 isolated_anon:0#012 active_file:27 inactive_file:621 isolated_file:0#012 unevictable:0 dirty:0 writeback:0 unstable:0#012 slab_reclaimable:4160 slab_unreclaimable:1950843#012 mapped:17 shmem:0 pagetables:1362 bounce:0#012 free:22524 free_pcp:30 free_cma:0
Mar  4 20:48:24 extranet2 kernel: Node 0 DMA free:15908kB min:132kB low:164kB high:196kB active_anon:0kB inactive_anon:0kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:15996kB managed:15908kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:0kB shmem:0kB slab_reclaimable:0kB slab_unreclaimable:0kB kernel_stack:0kB pagetables:0kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:0kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? yes
Mar  4 20:48:24 extranet2 kernel: lowmem_reserve[]: 0 3708 7794 7794
```

It seems the Linux is hanging after the CommVault Backup.

Do I have not enough memory on the server?

What does it mean "lowmem_reserve"?